# Column Hardware_ID get's automatically renamed to Hardware-ID

Tags: sql

can someone explain why this happens?

[image: HARDWARE_ID changes to HARDWARE-ID]

I don't like to call the column `[Hardware-ID]` if I can help it because I have to add brackets in my code if I use the dash... but it seems if I name id anything else (I tried `dbhardwareid` as well as `Hardware_ID`), I leave the table in a seemingly inconsistent status where the select shows a name different than the design view.

I deleted and recreated the table a number of times to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure the table exists under only one schema? My guess is that table exists under two different schemas, perhaps you are looking under one schema in Object Explorer and different schema in Query Window. Could you verify the schema?

Comment: that solved the problem @sam , thank you!!!
////
ie: after deleting the second table, all the weird behaviour disappeared and I was able to call the column whichever way I wanted!

Comment: Cool!!! I will add as answer, please mark it as answer so other would benefit from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that table exists under two different schemas, perhaps you are looking under one schema in Object Explorer and different schema in Query Window. Could you verify the schema?

Comment: that solved the problem @sam , thank you!!! //// ie: after deleting the second table, all the weird behaviour disappeared and I was able to call the column whichever way I wanted!